# Python Flask make a WTForm available to all templates

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a login form that should appear in all templates, so It's not convenient to pass it as parameter in every render_template(). I tried to put it in a environment globals like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_env.globals['loginform'] = LoginForm()
```

But it throws exception: `raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')`

How to do this correctly in Flask ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve that by using a Context Processor:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors